# finding number of occurences of any word in Rows

Tags: c#, linq

I have retrieved records from database which have a string field  "Route".like

```
No1) 2101-5340-5860-4923-3948-3459
No2) 4923-6574-9090-2000-3948-3400
No3) 2101-3400-4567-4444-5434-4923
```

I want to have this result at last:

```
              No_of_iteration
   --------------------------
    2101           2
    5340           1
    4923           3
    5860           1
    ...           ... and the rest
```

I was thinking of the solutions. one way is iteration through rows , put them all into the array. and then iterate through array for finding the number of occurrence.

what are other solutions for this problem?
any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you data to be something like this:-

```
List<string> data = new List<string>
{
    "2101-5340-5860-4923-3948-3459",
    "4923-6574-9090-2000-3948-3400",
    "2101-3400-4567-4444-5434-4923"
};
```

You can try this:-

```
var result = data.SelectMany(x => x.Split(new char[] { '-' }))
                 .GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new { Value = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
```

Working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BJBssL).

Answer (score 0):

You may can split the strings by "-", then use a dictionary  where the key is the string and the value is how many times it occurs.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need split by "-" and then perform simple grouping, something like so:

```
var result = entities.SelectMany(x => x.Route.Split('-'))
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select(x => new { Part = x.Key, No_of_iteration = x.Count() })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your solution, you will have to iterate through 1- 6000+ which is bad for performance.

I recommend you to create a class,

```
class Occurrence
{
 public static int number;
 public static int occurrence;
 ....
}
```

Then create an arraylist which contains instances of this class. For every number you see in database, check if is there an Occurrence with the number same as you see in database, then increase the occurrence value in it.

Probably there are better solutions than this, im just leaving here to give you an idea.